# Yahoo Pipes, how to get image from URL to thumbnail?

Tags: yahoo-pipes

i'm trying to get image for the RSS or XML URL link using Yahoo pipes.
is it even possible ?

Note: i'm talking about XML or RSS that looking like this

```
<title>
<description>
<link>
```

what i'm trying to do is get into the link and maybe do a REGEX to find the IMG SRC ( the html script it self ) and then rebuild the RSS with  and the link it self.

Comment: Yes this should be possible. Include a link to your pipe so we can see your source feed, and what you have tried. Hint: use the **Rename** operator to copy (or rename) the field with the `<img>` into `media:thumbnail.url`, use a **Regex** on `item.media:thumbnail.url` to get rid of everything except the url, and use a **Create RSS** operator to produce the output.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, I Don't want to sound like a newBie, but this is so complicated. Especially the regex thing. right now this is my simple pipe(at the end of the comment). I'm trying to have <image> with the link of the picture. Can you please show me how to edit it so I will learn from the results ? http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=ebad84fe564349dfac9fa390dc9eb7de